# Given two distributions of time intervals between events, which occurs first?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-variables

> Say I have two distributions $P_A(t), P_B(t)$ representing the time intervals between events which occur randomly. For instance, if $P_A(t)$ corresponds to a Poisson process, then it is a negative exponential.
>
> If I start the clock at $t=0$ and start recording events, what is the probability $a$ that an event of type A occurs before an event of type B?

Intuitively I would expect this to be $$\frac{\mu_A}{ \mu_A + \mu_B}$$
(where $\mu_i$ is $1/$mean of $P_i(t)$ for $i=A,B$) but I'm not sure how to prove this. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**: I assume $A$ and $B$ are independent processes.

Comment: If you were wondering if this was true in general (i.e., for any distributions $P_A,P_B$), it is not. Suppose $t_A$ is half-normally distributed with parameter $\sigma_A = 1$, and $t_B$ is half-normally distributed with parameter $\sigma_B = 2$. Then $P(t_A < t_B) \approx 0.704833$, while $\frac{\mu_A}{\mu_A + \mu_B} = \frac{1}{3}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not $100\%$ sure that this is what you want, so please let me know if you meant something different in your question. We have for two Poisson processes:
\begin{align}
P(t_A<t_B) &= \int_0^\infty P(t_A < t_B|t_B = t)P(t_B = t)\;dt \\
&= \int_0^\infty(1-e^{-\mu_A t})\mu_Be^{-\mu_B t}\;dt\\
&= \left[\frac{\mu_B}{\mu_A+\mu_B}e^{-(\mu_A+\mu_B)t}-e^{-\mu_bt}\right]_0^\infty \\
&=1 - \frac{\mu_B}{\mu_A + \mu_B} \\
&= \frac{\mu_A}{\mu_B + \mu_A}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. In general I don't require $P_A, P_B$ to be Poisson. But it appears that nothing can be said for general $P_A,P_B$ besides your first equation, as you gave a counterexample in the comments. Is that the case?

Comment: Yes, the half-normal distribution appears to be a counter example, and it is likely not the only one. If you’re interested, I can try to find additional counter examples when I have time!

Comment: @Dwagg I see that you have probably realized your error. But if you are interested, here is a little more on Poisson processes: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~gravner/MAT135B/materials/ch18.pdf

Comment: @Dwagg I made a similar mistake in giving the value of $\frac{\mu_A}{\mu_A+\mu_B}$ in my counterexample above. If $\mu_A$ is the inverse of the mean of $t_A$, then $\frac{\mu_A}{\mu_A+\mu_B} = \frac{2}{3}$. But it is still a counterexample

Comment: yes, thanks, I've similarly replaced $\mu_i =$ mean with $\mu_i = $ 1/mean in my question.